# How to make a global variable be visible outside event

Tags: python

I am trying to get the global variable inside the "OutputAnswerTest" Event to be detected by the if statment, yet I cannot seem to make it work. How do I do this?

```
#AnswerVar = IntVar()
AnswerBox = Entry(topFrame)
AdditionQuestionLeftSide = random.randint(0, 10)
AdditionQuestionRightSide = random.randint(0, 10)
AdditionQuestionRightSide = Label(topFrame, text= AdditionQuestionRightSide).grid(row=0,column=0)
AdditionSign = Label(topFrame, text="+").grid(row=0,column=1)
AdditionQuestionLeftSide= Label(topFrame, text= AdditionQuestionLeftSide).grid(row=0,column=2)
EqualsSign = Label(topFrame, text="=").grid(row=0,column=3)
AnswerBox.grid(row=0,column=4)


global answer

def OutputAnswerText(event):
    answer = AnswerBox.get()

AnswerBox.bind('<Return>', OutputAnswerText) # This is saying that if the "Return key (enter)" is pressed, run the handler, which the event I defined above

if Total  == answer:
    Correct = Label(topFrame, text="Correct").grid(row=2,column=3)
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you verified that OutputAnswerText is being called before before your if statement gets executed? Right now it looks as if the if statement will be executed right away, not after the user presses the return key.

Comment: sorry...I am new to this, would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare it outside the scope of your `global` statement:

```
In [7]: a = 2

In [8]: def test():
   ...:     global a
   ...:     a = 5
   ...:

In [9]: print a
2

In [10]: test()

In [11]: print a
```

For your use case:

```
answer = None

def OutputAnswerText(event):
    global answer
    answer = AnswerBox.get()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have now updated the code, moving the global variable outside the event ( I think that's what you meant), but I am still getting an error saying it is undefined from the if statement, yet the event has no problems.

Comment: Read the code I gave you; it needs to be defined in an outer scope for the `global` keyword to work in your inner scope. `a = 2; def test(): global a; a = 3;`